# Reciving posted object node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I've got an object:

```
var val = {username:'gilbertbw',password:'password',password2:'password',email:'email@email.com',firstname:'gilbert',lastname:'BW',test:true};
```

I run some validation against it and then post it to my node.js server:

```
console.log(
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/signup',
                data: val,
                success: function(){console.log('data posted')},
                dataType: "json"
            })
        );
```

On the server i have tryed just calling the object val:

```
console.log(val.username);
```

and pulling it from the post like I normally would:

```
val = req.param(val,null);
console.log(val.username);
```

But both times firebug spits out the 500 ISE:

```
    "{"error":{"message":"val is not defined","stack":"ReferenceError: val is not defined at exports.signup (C:\\Users\\Gilbert\\WebstormProjects\\NodeOfGames\\routes\\user.js:37:21)
```

If i just `console.log(val);` it prints null
The line in question is when I try to log val.username to console. How do you recive a posted object in node.js?

Comment: Assigning `console.log` to `success` is invalid. You're assigning it the return value of `console.log`, not telling it to execute it. You'd need to use `success: function(){ console.log(..); }`

Comment: @BradChristie it logs 'data posted' to the log just fine thought

Comment: You're right, it will--be preemptive to the ajax being called, not actually on the success callback.

Comment: gilbert, just to further clarify the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/zaGCX/

Comment: I suspect you are using Express, if so take a look at the accepted answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/node-js-extracting-post-data

Comment: @HectorCorrea thats the post I used to solve my problem (combined with the answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val` is a client-side variable. there is no way for the server to know you named this object "val".

`data: val` is just like:

```
data: {username:'gilbertbw',password:'password',password2:'password',email:'email@email.com',firstname:'gilbert',lastname:'BW',test:true}
```

so there is no `val` field for your server to find.

do this instead:

```
data: {
    "val": val
}
```

**edit:**

also, your line `req.param(val,null);` should be `req.param("val",null);`
or `val = req.body.val;`
([reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body))

Comment: the value of `val` is still `null` on the server, is there anything special I have to do to pick `val` up on the server?

Comment: I still get `val is not defined` but with `console.log(req.body.val)` I get the expected responce in the server log. so `val = req.body.val` works fine for me

Comment: glad it works. it'd be nice if you accept it as the correct answer.